# In Python, using pandasql: query return "Empty DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas, pandasql

In Python, using pandasql: query return "Empty DataFrame"

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as db
import pandasql
    dataSet = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data",header=None)
    type(dataSet)
    dataSet.columns = ['age', 'workclass','fnlwgt','education','education_num','marital_status','occupation','relationship'
                ,'race','sex','capital_gain','capital_loss','hours_per_week','native_country','salary']
    dataSet.head()
    from pandasql import sqldf
    q1 = "select distinct sex from dataSet where sex='Male';"
    pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
    print(pysqldf(q1))
```

Comment: please reformat the source code, it is unreadable

Answer (score 0):

For this data set I check actual data and found the whitespaces in the columns.

So first we need to perform cleansing over the data then we can perform transformation on that.

For cleansing we need to trim white spaces. for this purpose I have written function `trim_all_the_columns` that will remove all the whitespace

Code for above mentioned data set

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

#import required packages

import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as db
import pandasql as ps
from pandasql import sqldf 

#give the path location from where data is loaded, in your case give "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data"

inputpath=r'C:\Users\Z0040B9K\Desktop\SIGShowcase\adult.data.txt'

#Trim whitespace from ends of each value across all series in dataframe

def trim_all_the_columns(df):
    trim_strings = lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) is str else x
    return df.applymap(trim_strings)

#creating dataframe
dataSet = pd.read_csv(inputpath,header=None)

#calling trim function over the dataframe to remove all whitespaces
dataSet = trim_all_the_columns(dataSet)

type(dataSet)

dataSet.columns = ['age', 'workclass','fnlwgt','education','education_num','marital_status','occupation','relationship' ,'race','sex','capital_gain','capital_loss','hours_per_week','native_country','salary']

#sql query
q1 = "select distinct sex from dataSet where sex='Male';"
#this will return distinct result of **Male** column and that will be 0 
# If you add any other column like **age** or something else you will get result

#q1 = "select distinct age,sex from dataSet where sex='Male';"

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals()) 

#print result
print(pysqldf(q1))

#this also can be use to print result 

print(ps.sqldf(q1, locals()))
```

Find the resultant output: for query

```
q1 = "select distinct age, sex from dataSet where sex='Male';"
```

[image]

Find the result output for query

```
 q1 = "select distinct sex from dataSet where sex='Male';"
```

[image]